# Order of Magnitude of Cosmic Microwave Background Anisotropies

Tags: cosmology, temperature, cosmic-microwave-background

How does the statement about the anisotropies being of the order of $\frac{\Delta T}{T} \approx 10^-5$ which is often made in the literature (see, e.g. [Description of CMB Anisotropies by Scott and Smooth](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March05/Scott/Scott2.html)) square with Planck (thermodynamic) temperate maps showing variations of the order of $\pm 300 \mathrm{~\mu K_{CMB}}$ as seen [here](https://wiki.cosmos.esa.int/planck-legacy-archive/index.php/File:Cmb_inpaint_T_commander_v1.png)?

The cosmic microwave background has a mean temperature of $2.73 \mathrm{~K}$ and hence temperature fluctuations according to the literature should be roughly on a scale of about $\pm 10^{-5} \cdot 2.73 \mathrm{~K} \approx \pm 30 \mathrm{~\mu K}$. Of course those primordial fluctuations are to be understood with the dipole already subtracted.

On the other hand, temperature fluctuations of CMB maps such as those produced by the `Commander` component separation algorithm show anisotropies on a much larger scale. In those maps fluctuations are clearly not of the order of $\pm 30 \mathrm{~\mu K}$.

Hence, my question: how can both be true or is one just obsolete?